# Swift UI: Cannot load files via JS fetch in Webview HTML

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I was trying to load some existing website code into web view. One example html would be like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
    <script>
        const url = "/somefolder/model.txt"
        fetch(url)
           .then( r => r.text() )
           .then( t => console.log(t))
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is an example paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using `WKWebview` for this:

```
    struct SwiftUIWebview: UIViewRepresentable{
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let prefs = WKWebpagePreferences();
        prefs.allowsContentJavaScript=true;
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration();
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs;
        config.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
        let browser = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        return browser
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")!
        uiView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SwiftUIWebview()
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting errors while fetching the file. Looks like the URL is not considering the whole path for the app. I manually made the URL and fetched it from safari mobile browser of the device while app was running, It worked.

Need a solution that would consider the complete URL path for the file to be loaded.

[image]